# generate sql query from entity framework

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate sql query using .ToTraceString() in entity framework 3,5;
but I am getting the following error

**Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List  to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'**

I have the following code 
I need to generate sql query

> ```
>                   customers= ent.Customer
>                       .Include("UserType")
>                       .Include("User")
>                       .Where(c => c.Enabled == true)
>                   .ToList<Customer>();
> ```

How to get sql query generated by entity framework. I don't have sql profiler.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to call ToList() prior calling ToTraceString() because when you do you have  list returned which doesn't have ToTraceString() method